# Auth0 Service Usage In Lazy Loaded NG2 App

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, auth0

**Background -**

I recently took my working app and converted it to use `lazy loading`. The existing app had no issues and I use `Auth0` for `authentication`. After converting to `lazy loading` when I run the app everything appears to run ok. With the exception of one problem.

**Problem -**

When I click login from the `Auth0 widget` the app continues on as normal. But one of two things happen.

1. `Login` works successfully `authentication` the user.
2. `Login` fails with no error. 
   When it fails, it forwards to auth0 then redirects quickly to the home page without saving the token to the local storage.

I can login and out 10 times in a row. 1 of the logins will work then it will fail 9 times out of 10. I am not provided with any error messages or warnings. I can not even come up with a way to troubleshoot this issue because sometimes it works and when it does not work, nothing was changed to cause it to fail.

**Things I've Tried -**

1. Ran the application that does not use `lazy loading`.
   Works perfectly
2. Ran the lazy loading app from a different computer.
   Problem exists
3. Restarted Server.
   Problem exists
4. Changed the callback URL.
   Problem exists

**Questions -**

Does anyone know of a clever way to troubleshoot this issue?
Does anyone know what might cause such a thing to happen?

**Code Examples**

app.module.ts

```
/* Routing Module */
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Shared Stuff
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

//Page Modules
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiKeyGuard }          from "./shared/services/api.key.guard.service";
import { ProfileGuard }         from "./shared/services/profile.guard.service";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'benefits', loadChildren: './benefits/benefits.module#BenefitsModule' },
  { path: 'fcra', loadChildren: './fcra/fcra.module#FcraModule' },
  { path: 'croa', loadChildren: './croa/croa.module#CroaModule' },
  { path: 'tips', loadChildren: './tips/tips.module#TipsModule' },
  { path: 'maintenance', loadChildren: './maintenance/maintenance.module#MaintenanceModule' },
  { path: 'verify-email', loadChildren: './verify-email/verify-email.module#VerifyEmailModule' },
{ path: 'profile', canActivate: [ProfileGuard], loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule' },
  { path: 'recommendations', canActivate: [ApiKeyGuard], loadChildren: './recommendations/recommendations.module#RecommendationsModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

/shared/shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

//Services
import { ApiKeyGuard }                      from './services/api.key.guard.service';
import { ProfileGuard }                     from './services/profile.guard.service';
import { Auth }                             from './services/auth.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CollapseModule,
        ChartsModule,
        TabsModule.forRoot(),
        ToastyModule.forRoot(),
        SignaturePadModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        BreadcrumbsComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LsideComponent,
        RsideComponent,
        NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
        SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
        AsideToggleDirective
    ],
    providers: [
          ApiKeyGuard,
        ProfileGuard,
        Auth
        ],
  exports: [
      CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        HeaderComponent,
        BreadcrumbsComponent
        ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

breadcrumb is a shared component which lives in the shared directory. This component is rendered in every page that appears on the website and is injected to `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`.

The auth service is injected into the breadcrumb component.

```
import { Component }                                from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }    from '@angular/router';
import { Auth }                     from './../services/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'breadcrumbs',
    templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html'
})
export class BreadcrumbsComponent {
    constructor(private router:Router, private route:ActivatedRoute, private auth: Auth) {}
    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

The login function from auth.service is called in the breadcrumb.component.html file.

breadcrumb.component.html

```
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="auth.login()" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">Login / SignUp</a>
```

Auth Service

```
import { Injectable }                      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper }      from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router }                          from '@angular/router';
import { myConfig }                        from './auth.config';
import {Http, Response, Headers, URLSearchParams}         from '@angular/http';
import { User }                            from './../models/user';
import { LogReg }                          from './../models/logreg';
import { STATICS }                          from './../static/static';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

var options = {
    theme: {
    logo: 'assets/img/logo.png',
    primaryColor: '#779476'
    },
    languageDictionary: {
    emailInputPlaceholder: "email@example.com",
    title: "Login or SignUp"
  },
 };

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, options, {});
  userProfile: Object;
  logreg: LogReg;
  user: User;

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http ) {

    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.idToken);
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error: any, profile: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return;
        }

          // Login Or Register User On Our Server
        this.logreg = new LogReg(profile.email_verified, profile.email);

        this.checkRegister(this.logreg).subscribe(
            (res)=>{
              console.log("Hey this runs");
              console.log(res);
                if (res.email_verified === false) {
                 localStorage.removeItem('profile');
                 localStorage.removeItem('api_key');
                 localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
                 localStorage.removeItem('user');
                 this.userProfile = null;
                 this.user = null;
                 this.router.navigate(['/verify-email']);

                }
            else if (res.api_key_exist === false) {
                  console.log("Hey this works")
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile = profile;
                console.log(this.userProfile);
                this.user = new User(profile.email, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', res.api_key_exist, '')
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                this.router.navigate(['/profile']);

            } else if (res.api_key_exist === true) {
                this.user = new User(res.user.email,
                    res.user.first_name,
                    res.user.middle_name,
                    res.user.last_name,
                    res.user.dob,
                    res.user.phone,
                    res.user.street_address,
                    res.user.city_address,
                    res.user.state_address,
                    res.user.zip_address,
                    res.user.client_ss,
                    res.api_key_exist,
                    res.api_key);
                console.log(this.user);
                localStorage.setItem('api_key', JSON.stringify(res.api_key));
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
            }
        },
            (err)=>{ console.log(err);}

        );
      });
      this.lock.hide();
    });
  }

  public checkRegister(model: LogReg) {
      // Parameters obj-
      let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('email', model.email);
      params.set('email_verified', model.email_verified);

      return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_LOGIN,
          { search: params }).map((res:Response) =>  res.json());
      }

  public login() {
    this.lock.show();
  }

  private get accessToken(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }

  private get apiKey(): string {
      var apiKey = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('api_key'));
        return apiKey
    }

  public authenticated(): boolean {
    try {
        var jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
        var token = this.accessToken;
        if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
  }

  public logout() {
    var apiKeyExist = this.user.api_key_exist;
    console.log(apiKeyExist);
    if (apiKeyExist === true) {
      let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      params.set('email', this.user.email);
      params.set('api_key', this.apiKey);

      localStorage.removeItem('profile');
      localStorage.removeItem('api_key');
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.userProfile = null;
      this.user = null;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');

      return this.http.get(STATICS.API_BASE + STATICS.API_LOGOUT,
        { search: params })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.user = null;
          console.log(this.user);
        });
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('profile');
      localStorage.removeItem('api_key');
      localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.userProfile = null;
      this.user = null;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    }
  };
}
```

******************** UPDATE *************************
In shared.module.ts I made a change.

I changed the export to this at the bottom of the file,

```
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [Auth]
    };
  }
}
```

Now I have been able to login and out 5 times in a row successfully. But the image of the user does not show up that is supplied from the auth0 response. I am wondering now if it is still a little glitchy because I need to make sure to specify forRoot and forChild in the right places.

I am specifying all of the routes in the app-routing.moduel.ts file which is in the root of the application which can be seen in the above code.

In each of the modules which are lazy loaded there is a routes file. Here is an example of home routes file

home-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home',    component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

Notice that the forChild is on the RouterModule.

Is this configured correctly? Also should I be adding shared.module.ts to every module or only?

Comment: Can you please provide some small code snippets on how your lazy loading is configured in your routing, and where you import or provide your authentication service? Include your version of angular and the router.

Also, can you please elaborate on what is specifically happening in case #2, when it fails with no errors? Are you not being redirected by Auth0, are you not getting tokens, or **how does it appear to "fail"?**

Comment: I updated my question as you asked. I added an explanation to the number 2 scenario and I added all the code explaining the process. If you can help me figure this out I would appreciate it. I can not even figure out how to troubleshoot it. I console.log in the auth service. When the login works the console.log works. When the login does not work the console.log does not output. So sometimes the authservice works and sometimes it does not.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your auth and lazy-loading. From your code it looks like the `Auth` service is eagerly loaded (via `SharedModule`) so it shouldn't be impacted by loading a bunch of *other* modules lazily. Can you confirm that **all auth-related tasks** are performed **within the Auth service** and that this service is NOT lazy-loaded?

Comment: It is loaded by the shared module. That is correct. And yes the service should work from my understanding. The show widget function is in the auth service. So if it was not loading correctly why would it even show in the first place?  Right? I am super confused by this. Cause like I said the only thing I have changed is added lazy loading.

Comment: It appears that what is happening is that the auth service is stopping mid way through. Sometimes it clears and sometimes it does not. Would you mind taking a look at my auth service and seeing if you can see what would cause it to stop sometimes but continue other times? I updated my question and put the whole file at the bottom.

Comment: Hey I made a huge break through. Luckily. Would you please read the end of my question where I added the update?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that when it fails it is actually redirecting you but not saving the tokens, I have a theory that the Auth0 redirect is going to some page in your application where either your Auth service has not been initialized, or that the token fragments are being cleared by the routing.

Since angular is doing client side routing **the Auth0 redirect is not always directed back to the current visible url** by default, but more likely the last full navigation. Sometimes when you are testing that might be `"/"` and since you have a redirect immediately on the root route, the tokens passed as fragments will be cleared by angular, thus might not be picked up by the Auth service.

There are two things you can try. Test both proposed solutions individually and combined.

**1. Explicitly specify where Auth0 should redirect with the acquired tokens**
*I recommend you try this first*

```
// in your Auth service
var options = {
  theme: {
    logo: 'assets/img/logo.png',
    primaryColor: '#779476'
  },
  languageDictionary: {
    emailInputPlaceholder: "email@example.com",
    title: "Login or SignUp"
  },
  auth: {                              // Added
    redirectUrl: window.location.href, // Added
    responseType: 'token',             // Added
  }                                    // Added
};
```

**2. Replace the listener for `lock.on('authenticated', ..)` with listening to router changes**

In your Auth service constructor, replace the authenticated event listener with the following. Remember to include the additional logic you have when getting the `authResult`.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http ) {
    /*...*/

    router
    .events
    .filter(event => event.constructor.name === 'NavigationStart')
    .filter(event => (/access_token|id_token|error/).test(event.url))
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.lock.resumeAuth(window.location.hash, (error, authResult) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            // TODO: Add the logic you currently have in the authenticated listener
        });
    });

    /*...*/
}
```

The second example is straight from the [Angular 2 Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#use-with-hashlocationstrategy)

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I tried your suggestions and the same problem persists. I am going to strip out all the logic and just try to save the token. Mabe running through it line by line will reveal the problem. What I cant wrap my head around is why this worked perfectly before lazy loading and now it does not. Or worst why it works 1 time out of 20.

Comment: Hey I made a huge break through. Luckily. Would you please read the end of my question where I added the update?